# Can someone explain this line: Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian

I've been adapting [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpc_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpc-iris-py) to work with 20 features instead of 2. I've got most of it working but it's giving me an error on this line:

```
Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier) for predict_proba simply talks about an input of x, not x and y, and in addition we have the ravel() going on here. So was wondering what was going on? The error I'm getting happens when it tries to do the concatenation:

```
338         res = _nx.concatenate(tuple(objs), axis=self.axis)
    339         return self._retval(res)
    340 

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

But I've checked that the number of rows are the same in both my xx (test input) and yy (test label).

Comment: the example works fine for me. can you post your code so i can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems to work fine.

The key is this line: `y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1`.

It shows that yy here is not related to the label as You might thought, but is actually the second dimension. So the concatenation code is simply creating a grid of all features, which is then fed into the model to form a prediction.

In more detail :

You can go throught the code line by line and see what happens.

Before the

```
Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

If you store the `np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]` in a variable with name `vrb`

```
vrb = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
```

Then you can see what is it

```
vrb.shape
vrb
```

Results:

```
(61600L, 2L)

array([[ 3.3 ,  1.  ],
       [ 3.32,  1.  ],
       [ 3.34,  1.  ],
        ...,
       [ 8.84,  5.38],
       [ 8.86,  5.38],
       [ 8.88,  5.38]])
```

This means that the results of the `np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]` is an array with 61600 lines (samples) and 2 features (columns).

Using `clf.predict_proba(vrb)` you predict the labels of these samples.

The matrix "vrb" must have the same "second dimension" (number of columns) as the matrix that you used for the fitting of the classifier (training stage).

To test this use:

```
X.shape
```

The result is:

```
(150L, 2L)
```

You can clearly see that the training data (X) have 2 columns (features).

If you upload your code and data, I could help more.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. 

The key is this line: `y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1`  It shows that yy here is not related to the label as I mistakenly thought, but is actually the second dimension. So the concatenation code is simply creating a grid of all features, which is then fed into the model to form a prediction. When extending this to 20 features, I shall have to have an xx, yy, zz etc.. so that I am concatenating 20 features.

Comment: If you could just insert the above paragraph into the top of your answer I can award you the points, as I appreciate you taking the time to reply and help me think through it.

Comment: @user1761806  I added your paragraph